# How to get which items were deleted from a BindingList

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am using a `BindingList` in my code because I want the extra features that `ObservableCollection` is lacking. Mainly the `ItemChanged` event being raised when one of the items in the list that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` has a property that has changed.

But, on the code that subscribes to the `ListChanged` event I am having difficulty to get which items were deleted.
The event, when raised, gives me the index of the item for which "something happend" on it.
So in the case of `ItemAdded` and `ItemChanged` events, I can get the item directly using the index. But in the case of deleted? How can I retrieve which item was deleted?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez Yeah, for some reason searching did not yield that result. Now I need to wait for the bounty time to finish before closing. I tried closing it myself but because of the bounty we need to wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A BindingList by itself is not able to perform this function.

There is an excellent answer that shows how to extend the BindingList to get that functionality.
[Get Deleted Item in ItemChanging event of BindingList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339233/get-deleted-item-in-itemchanging-event-of-bindinglist)

Comment: O I see that Juan Carlos Rodriguez also linked this already

Comment: I was actually thinking of deleting my question but as it seems it would be ideal for an answer to be deleted before question is. My search did not return the duplicate question. I am unable to close it as duplicate due to the bounty

Comment: @JohnDemetriou - in these situations its better to award the bounty then it will let you (or I) close as a duplicate. No point throwing away 50pts.

Comment: @JeremyThompson award it where though?

Comment: @JeremyThompson voted to close